# How can I verify that CNTLM works correctly?

Tags: windows, command-line, terminal, proxy, ntlm

I had installed and configured CNTLM on my Windows 7 machine.

CNTLM is running and I can see it in Process. I have problems with a development tool that points to http://localhost:3128, I have doubts that CNTML doesn't work correctly.

**Question:**

How can I get a url form command line passing by CNTLM proxy?

**Version:**

```
Windows 7 
cntlm   0.92.3
```

Comment: You have curl installed ?

Comment: Yes, I have it installed.

Comment: Right now your question is not about programming. You can use curl with a proxy and/or with ntlm authentication to test directly or through CNTLM. I think you should ask on SuperUser (or ServerFault).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open CMD (Windows Prompt), navigate to the Cntlm folder and type:

```
cntlm -M http://google.com
```

This will test the access to this URL.